# IMX6Q using SPI-NOR flash keeps crashing!

Tags: spi, microprocessor, freescale, nor-flash

I'm kinda new to the whole board bring-up thing so please be patient with me.

**The problem:**

- I'm getting lots of ext4-errors randomly and the whole thing eventually crashes after a few reboots.

```
    [  305.118556] EXT4-fs (mtdblock2): error count since last fsck: 4
    [  305.124528] EXT4-fs (mtdblock2): initial error at time 1651167944: htree_dirblock_to_tree:1098: inode 210: block 8608
    [  305.135193] EXT4-fs (mtdblock2): last error at time 1651167945: htree_dirblock_to_tree:1098: inode 224: block 8611
```

- When i do a "df -h" it tells me that my memory is almost all used up.

```
    Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
    /dev/root                60.6M     52.7M      3.0M  95% /
    devtmpfs                500.4M         0    500.4M   0% /dev
    tmpfs                   500.9M         0    500.9M   0% /dev/shm
    tmpfs                   200.4M      9.8M    190.6M   5% /run
    tmpfs                     4.0M         0      4.0M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    tmpfs                   500.9M         0    500.9M   0% /tmp
    tmpfs                   500.9M     12.0K    500.9M   0% /var/volatile
```

- I'm also told that seeing /dev/root means I'm still on initramfs and that my actual root has not yet been mounted? But the changes to the files have been retained even after rebooting.

**What I've gotten so far:**

- I've managed to create my U-Boot, zImage (linux kernel 6.0.8), dtb and rootfs in
  Yocto (Kirkstone).
- I'm loading my rootfs into my SPI-NOR flash using UUU by using the sf
  write command directly to a specific address: 0xB00000
- My rootfs is a .ext4 file i.e. IMAGE_FSTYPE="ext4" and its roughly 70MB and I've allocated 117MB for /dev/mtdblock2 in my SPI-NOR flash.
- i've partitioned my SPI-NOR flash (128MB) in my device tree:

```
    flash: spi-nor@0 {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <1>;
        compatible = "winbond,w25q01jv", "jedec,spi-nor";
        spi-max-frequency = <20000000>;
        reg = <0>;
        
        partition@0 {
             label = "uboot";
             reg = <0x00000000 0x100000>;
         };
    
         partition@0x100000 {
             label = "kernelanddtb";
             reg = <0x100000 0xA00000>;
         };
    
         partition@0xB00000 {
             label = "rootfs";
             reg = <0xB00000 0>;
         };
    };
```

- my `bootargs=console=ttymxc0,115200 root=/dev/mtdblock2 rw`

I understand that SPI-NOR flash works totally differently from eMMCs and that they don't actually have partitions or blocks so most of the resources online doesn't cater to my use case.

Can someone with experience in this please help!

Thanks!

Comment: Apart from the hardware interface, spi-nor and emmc store data much the same. Clearly the spi-nor has partitions as they’re described in your device tree and blocks are a file system construct.  You might want to double check your kernel configuration for the mtd device.

Comment: Just curious, why is the size 0 for your rootfs partition? If I understand correctly, reg = <0xB00000 0> means this partition starts from address 0xB00000 and have size of 0, this obviously could cause problem for the kernel.

Comment: @Jimmy.D 0 here just means to use all memory space left